# knockout.js foreach binding in comment not working as expected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've created a JSFiddle with my problem here http://jsfiddle.net/benjishults/PMeJh/1/.

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="with: jobBeingViewed">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-bind="text: 'Days offset from ' + runtime"></th>
                <th>-7</th>
                <th>-6</th>
                <th>-5</th>
                <th>-4</th>
                <th>-3</th>
                <th>-2</th>
                <th>-1</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: 'Actuals Availability'"></td>
                <!-- ko.foreach: actuals -->
                <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function VM() {
    function Job() {
        this.runtime="2014-03-07";
        this.actuals = ko.observableArray([1,1,1,1,1,1,1]);
    }

    this.jobBeingViewed = ko.observable(new Job());

}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

On the page, the second row has only two columns populated and it looks like this:

```
Actuals Availability        [object Object]
```

I expect it to look like this:

```
Actuals Availability        1       1        1        1        1        1        1
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried adding parens.  I've tried referring to actuals through $root.jobBeingViewed.actuals.  Neither worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is an errant dot in `ko.foreach`

```
<!-- ko.foreach: actuals -->
```

should be

```
<!-- ko foreach: actuals -->
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/PMeJh/2/

Comment: Thanks!  After spending hours trying to figure this out, I actually figured it out and was posting my own answer when yours showed up.  You get credit for the speed!